# Issue with MySQL's "SELECT INTO"

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "open_hours" that has 4 columns:

```
0 -> id (INT)
1 -> group (VARCHAR)
2 -> start (TIME)
4 -> end (TIME)
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT `start`, `end` INTO @start_time, @end_time FROM open_hours
WHERE `group` = 'DFGDDFGDF'; -- This group does not exist in the table!
SELECT @start_time, @end_time;
```

I get this:

```
# @start_time, @end_time
'05:30:00', '23:59:00'
```

The values returned belong to the only group that *does* exist in the table. I was hoping to get 'NULL' instead. What is happening?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results.

Comment: *What is happening?* i think the variables still contained data from a previous run or query where the group data was found .

Comment: How could I miss this! You're right. I set the initial values of my variables to NULL and now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Those rows look a bit like columns

Comment: Mea culpa... Yes, they are "columns" not rows.

Comment: @SCilek if you found the answer yourself, you should *always* post it so others can learn from your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to: @Raymond Nijland

The problem was that the values contained values from a previous query. Setting them to NULL before assigning them solved the problem.